# How to force numeric variable to read as categorical in r using summary() ?

Tags: r, modeling

I have x = 1,2,3,4 which is my categorical variable 
but when I use summary() it automatically thinks that this is discrete : so I would get something like this

Min : 
1st Qu.:
Median :

---

But what I want is to give me just the frequency for this variable within the summary()

1: 
2:
3:
4:

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
> x <- seq(1:10)

> summary(as.factor(x))
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Or, if you want to permanently assign x as categorical variable in a dataframe named mydata, do this before the `summary()` call:

```
mydata$x <- factor(mydata$x)
```

(Spending an hour or two with any of [the many books or online intros](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/r/info) to R and typing out the examples is a smart investment and saves a lot of time.)

Comment: Hi MattBagg , Thank you !! this works , But what do I need to do if I have multiple of this type of variables in "mydata" that I want to use summary function  e.i. summary(mydata)

Comment: OMG , this awesome !! thank you ! I am pretty new in R , Thank you thank you thank !!